# I am unable to start the bamboo as a window service in my pc

Tags: bamboo

I have downloaded the bamboo windows 64bit, in the installation process, I set the *bamboo installation directory* in my `C:\Program Files\Bamboo` and my *bamboo_home directory* in `C:\Users\<current-user>\Bamboo-home`. When I start the `StartBamboo.bat` file it's said that **The service name is invalid**

*And If I click on `InstallAsService` to install the service then nothing happens and even in `services.msc` I didn't find the bamboo service from where I start the service.*

**I got the error while running the bat file `StartBamboo.bat` that is given below-**

> The service name is invalid.
>
> More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the service name has an invalid character. See in the services list, or you can try changing the name in the "InstallAsService.bat" and "UninstallService.bat". You can change the name in the install and remove commands.

Comment: Yeah ,, Before starting the `StartBamboo.bat` ,First, I need to install the service , So I run the command in cmd i.e ` C:\Bamboo\bin: service.bat install Bamboo`. After that I got resolved the issue which I'm getting the service name is invalid . And then successfully run the bamboo in my system. And thank you for your reply !! 

Comment: Please can you mark this answer as valid? Thanks!